# Loops and Modulo

Tags: c++

I'm not sure why this code isn't working as intended.
"input % 7 != 3  || input % 7 != 4)". I'm saying if input modulo 7 does not equal to 3 or 4 then stay in the loop. however when I enter 10 it still doesn't work when 10 modulo 7 equals to 3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int input;
int count = 1;
cout << "Please Enter a positive integer that is 3 or 4 modulo 7: ";
cin >> input;

while (input <= 0 || input % 7 != 3  || input % 7 != 4){
count++;
cout << count << "tries, " << "please try again: ";
cin >> input; 
}

cout << "Congratulations, you passed";
 return 0;    
}
```

Comment: It will loop if _any_ of these conditions are true. **1.** `The input is 0 or less.` **2.** `The input/7 doesn't have a remainder of 3.` **3.** `The input/7 doesn't have a remainder of 4.` --- Can you see now why it isn't working how you expect?

Comment: Are you sure about OR (||) and not AND(&&)? `10%7!=3` is false but `10%7!=4` is true. So the loop successfully moves to the next iteration. You need to use `&&` if you want the control to move out in case of 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm saying if input modulo 7 does not equal to 3 or 4 then stay in the loop.

In that case, you need to change your condition to this:

```
while (input <= 0 || (input % 7 != 3  && input % 7 != 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical error, here, this is the condition you might need:

```
while (input <= 0 || (input % 7 != 3  && input % 7 != 4)){
```

You want to stay in the loop while the modulu is different from both 3 and 4.

Comment: Note for readers: A nice and easy way to avoid these kinds of logical errors is to break them up into testable functions. e.g. `while (input <= 0 || remainderIsInvalid(input)) { ... }`. If there is a logical mistake, you'll usually notice just by reading it.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure why this code isn't working as intended. "input % 7 != 3 || input % 7 != 4)". I'm saying if input modulo 7 does not equal to 3 or 4 then stay in the loop

No, you're not!

You're saying if *input modulo 7* does not equal *3*, or *input modulo 7* does not equal *4*, stay in the loop.

That condition always holds because *input modulo 7* cannot be both *3* and *4* at the same time.

This kind of rewrite of logical connectives is actually an English mistake; although colloquially accepted in English, it's not in C++.

You meant *"if input modulo 7 does not equal 3, **and** input modulo 7 does not equal 4, stay in the loop"*, i.e. `input % 7 != 3 && input % 7 != 4`.